# MYSQL Error - Duplicate key on write or update

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `demare`.`shop` (
    `shop_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `shop_image` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `shop_price` FLOAT(6,2) NOT NULL,
    `cart_id` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`shop_id`),
INDEX `cart_id_idx` (`cart_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `cart_id`
  FOREIGN KEY (`cart_id`)
  REFERENCES `demare`.`shopping cart` (`cart_id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I have an error. My 'shop' table cannot be created as I have error:

> 121 Duplicate key on write or update.

I have provided the codes. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: share `shopping cart` table ?

Comment: Improved formatting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error: Can't create table (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834380/mysql-error-cant-create-table-errno-121-duplicate-key-on-write-or-update)

Comment: In your specific case: a key that is named `cart_id` is very likely to be used somewhere else. Adding the table name to the index can prevent such things (e.g. something like `fk_shop_cart_id`).

Answer (score 2):

Problem exist because the foriegn key exist in memory, if possible drop the database and start again.